# How to display the React Axios progress bar?

Tags: reactjs, axios

[image]

I want the result screen

My componentDidMount ()

```
  _isMounted = false;
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    var page = 0; // 공정 라인 수

    //비가동 현황 불러오기
    let oprationStatus = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/process/FM')
      .then(response => {
        var output = response && response.data;
          //비가동 현황
          NonOperationalStatus.data.series[0][0] = output.list[page].nop_000; // 계획
          NonOperationalStatus.data.series[0][1] = output.list[page].nop_001; // 재료
          NonOperationalStatus.data.series[0][2] = output.list[page].nop_002; // 금형
          NonOperationalStatus.data.series[0][3] = output.list[page].nop_003; // 설비
          NonOperationalStatus.data.series[0][4] = output.list[page].nop_004; // 사람
          NonOperationalStatus.data.series[0][5] = output.list[page].nop_etc; // 기타
      });
    }
    //가동율 등등 기본 정보 가져오기
    let getProcess = () => {
      oprationStatus();
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/process/FM')
      .then(response => {
        var output = response && response.data;
          if(this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({
              data: output.list[page]
            })          
          if(page < output.list.length-1) {
            page++;
          } else if(page == output.list.length-1) {
            page = 0;
            this.props.history.push('/hdprocess')
          }
          setTimeout(getProcess, 1000 * 5); // 매 5초마다 값 가져옴
        }
      });
    }
      getProcess();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
```

This code gets the data from the API server at 5 second intervals and routes it to the next page.

What I want is to display a progress icon as the picture above while the asynchronous communication is loading.

Let me know if you have a good alternative

Comment: you can use conditional rendering. like you can define one variable isLoading in your state and update it as per your requirement.like when you making api call set it to true and when you getting data from server then make it to false.and use that isLoading in your application like isLoading then <Loader/> else <YourCompoent/>

Comment: let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 0):

Initially use a progress or spinner component.
Use it until a valid Response is return from the Axios Function, if a valid Response is attained, change the spinner(progres bar) Component to the actual component